# CakePHP removeFromTree always beforeDelete

Tags: php, cakephp, tree, cakephp-1.3

On CakePHP 1.3 I have a tree and always before deleting a tree record I have to remove the record from the tree because I dont want its' children deleted.
One option is to do `removeFromTree` inside the controller always before deleting a record, but the delete action is also used by other non tree model.

So what I can think is to put `removeFromTree` in the `beforeDelete` callback. Is this the best I can do or do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Putting it in your model’s `beforeDelete()` method is fine, and what I would suggest. Go with that.

Comment: how to do it inside a custom behavior. This does not work:
 `function beforeDelete(&$model){
  if(!$model->removeFromTree($model->id)){
   return false;
  }
  return true;
 }`

Comment: if I put it in the model - it works, but creating a behavior with the above code and adding it in the `$actAs` does nothing - no error and still all children deleted